# "I didn't think of it [at first/before]" — which one is acceptable?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> I like the idea of contract signing with my customers. I didn't think of it before.

Should I say *at first* instead of *before*, or is the sentence acceptable as it is?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. As it stands your question is incomplete. Please edit to show the research you did and the reason you still needed the help of an expert. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is fine. You'd use *at first* when you have a supporting sentence that follows the logic. like:

I didn't think of it at first, but (now) I like the idea of contract signing with my customers.
or
 I like the idea of contract signing with my customers. I didn't think of it at first but later I realized so.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't think of it before, because I wasn't interested in the subject.

Comment: Try to provide the *why* of it, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.